# android.view.InflateException - cannot find reason

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is my fragment `inputtext_fragment.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/inputtextfragm"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputtext_layout"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        ...>

        ...

    </LinearLayout>
</fragment>
```

inputText fragment in java:

```
package de.company.android.inputtext;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class InputTextFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        try {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.inputtext_fragment, container, false);
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the activity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    tools:context="de.company.android.testview.MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000">

    ...

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/console"
        android:name="de.company.android.inputtext.InputTextFragment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I get the following error on launch, when the content view of the activity is set `onCreate()`:

> D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: de.company.android.testview, PID: 573
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.company.android.testview/de.company.android.testview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #153: Binary XML file line #153: Error inflating class fragment
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #153: Binary XML file line #153: Error inflating class fragment
                   ...

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment de.company.android.inputtext.InputTextFragment did not create a view.
>                         at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2253)
>                         at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:99)
>                         at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6085)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
>                         at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
>                         at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:479) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2400) 
>                         at de.company.android.testview.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:1697) 
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

This is the error logged inside `catch`:

```
W/System.err: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
W/System.err:     at de.company.android.inputtext.InputTextFragment.onCreateView(InputTextFragment.java:23)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2281)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1142)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1246)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2223)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:99)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6085)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
...
W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err:     at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:362)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:620)
W/System.err:     at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:598)
W/System.err:     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2214)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater$FactoryMerger.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:192)
W/System.err:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:766)
W/System.err:   ... 33 more
```

I cannot find out what is wrong. The activity and the fragment are in different modules, but everything is configured right so that the `de.company.android.inputtext` utils are correctly referenced.

Comment: You're trying to inflate the fragment into itself. The layout of a fragment does not have `fragment` as root. Use a regular view group such as FrameLayout or LinearLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input_text_fragment.xml should not be inside of a Fragment tag.  It should be inside the appropriate type of Layout.  The fragment tag goes only in main_activity.xml where you want the fragment to appear.

Comment: Thanks! Why doesn't Android Studio complain about that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the fragment from inputtext_fragment.xml layout,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/inputtext_layout"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        ...>

        ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment de.company.android.inputtext.InputTextFragment did not create a view.

You can't return a null view in onCreateView.

Comment: It does not return a view because the XML is not inflated. I want to know **why** it is not inflated. `R.layout.inputtext_fragment` exists and the fragment's XML is correct (else the compiler had complained).

Comment: You didn't give us the stack trace for that.  YOu only gave us the one for the crash-  which is because the view is null

Comment: OK, I added the original error logged inside catch.